# Failing to Retrieve Data from Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from a firebase real-time database and I am following this tutorial from the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-start.
For my front-end framework I am using Svelte.

I set up the database in `firebase.js`.

### firebase.js

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCHL9UcT3TtvgQwt7N3DbLjRon9gKPFjA0",
    authDomain: "lyrics-and-quotes.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://lyrics-and-quotes-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "lyrics-and-quotes",
    storageBucket: "lyrics-and-quotes.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "492758193692",
    appId: "1:492758193692:web:60ab73db53010e7fa7b1d9",
    measurementId: "G-T33YSTR82R",
};

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
export const db = getDatabase(app);

// Initialize auth
export const auth = getAuth();

// Initialize Google auth provider
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

On one of my front-end components, I have:

```js
    import { db } from '../database/firebase';
    const postsRef = db.ref('posts');
```

However, I get the error: `Posts.svelte:5 Uncaught TypeError: db.ref is not a function`.

Comment: Sorry, but why are you refering nodejs admin firebase documentation? I think you should be reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write) instead. Also, keep an eye on the version of firebase you are using and docs you are reading. AFAICS you are using firebase v9 but there is a lot of articles for v8, so be careful.

Comment: I am trying to sort the data by key and I thought I am supposed to use the `orderByKey()` function as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Query#orderbykey).

Comment: Also I am trying to use V9. Does that mean I should import `ref` from `firebase/database` instead of doing `db.ref()`?

Comment: Again, you are reading v8 docs while using v9 lib, they are very different. Here is the [sorting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) example.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve this by using the `query` function to get the reference and passing it to `onValue`.

Answer (score 1):

`app` is not defined in your `firebase.js` file.

You need to do

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getDatabase(app);
```

as shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#access-firebase).